# Read data from s3 using date format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have data is s3 location,trying to read data from s3

```
val repdate=spark.sql("select date_sub(current_timestamp(),1)")
println("repdate"+repdate)
```

output  or repdate is 2021-12-11

but in s3 location its s3://qa/test1/12-11-2021/, trying to use date_format

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfdate=date_format(repdate),"MM-DD-YYYY").as(format)
```

[image]

getting error

> "type mismatch"

```
val df=spark.read.format(""com.databricks.csv").option("header","true").
load(s"s3://bnsdfasdf/coa/dfdate/evvventz")
```

Is there a simple workaround using cast(unix_timestamp)?

tried :

```
 val repdate=spark.sql("select date_sub(current_timestamp(),1)")
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
   val dfdate=(""" select date_format(repdate),"MM-DD-YYYY").as(format) """)
```

[image]

but got path does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the error, so it's hard to give a precise answer,
Try this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")    
val dfdate=date_format(repdate),"MM-DD-YYYY").as(format)
```

Comment: thankyou,  butgot similar error after trying your command

Comment: check the type of 'replaydate' , error is typecasting problem.  First, make sure your  `replaydate` is a string. If it is , then try this

` to_date(col("replaydate"),"MM-DD-YYYY")`